# How to to properly install and run OCR for php on windows

Tags: php, tesseract

I'm following this tutorial for Tesseract: http://www.sitepoint.com/ocr-in-php-read-text-from-images-with-tesseract/

I'm very new to this and all the terms used VM ssh Debian and so on confuses me. All I need to know is how to download the Tesseract that supports PHP and start uploading images and read the text out of it.

The guide in the tutorial is beyond my ability to understand. Someone please guide me how to get this done.

I've downloaded files from https://github.com/lukaswhite/ocr-php-tesseract-example and placed inside a folder named ocr in root directory. Next?